# pmap total always in kilobytes?

Tags: linux, pmap

Does the Linux command "pmap" always give the total memory usage in kilobytes?

```
$ pmap 3208920 | tail -n 1 
 total            71836K
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It’s always [shown in kibibytes](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/d4ecd5cb3575928000eb7dc796626c92ff3d380b/src/pmap.c#L751):

```c
            if (sizeof(long) == 8)
                /* Translation Hint: keep total string length
                 * as 24 characters. Adjust %16 if needed*/
                printf(_(" total %16ldK\n"),
                       (total_shared + total_private_writeable +
                    total_private_readonly) >> 10);
            else
                /* Translation Hint: keep total string length
                 * as 16 characters. Adjust %8 if needed*/
                printf(_(" total %8ldK\n"),
                       (total_shared + total_private_writeable +
                    total_private_readonly) >> 10);
```

(Shifting right by 10 is equivalent to dividing by 1,024.)

Comment: (and since that should all be multiples of 4096, giving the info in KiB shouldn't lose information)